# Golang проверка на null в запросе select

Tags: postgresql, golang, select, null

Код:

```
type SelectNar struct {

    Id          int64   `json:"id"`
    NumberNar       string  `json:"number_nar"`
    DateOpenNar     string  `json:"date_open_nar"`
    VrachOrtoped        string  `json:"vrach_ortoped"`
    DateStartProduction string  `json:"date_start_production"`
    VrachTechnic        string  `json:"vrach_technic"`
    DateCloseNar        string  `json:"date_close_nar"`
    Sum         string  `json:"sum"`
}

func EditListNarGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    bks := models.EditModelListNarGet(r.FormValue("id"))
    b, err := json.Marshal(bks)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s \n", b)
    }
}

func EditModelListNarGet(id string) []*SelectNar {
    rows := db.Select(`
    SELECT
    id, number_nar, date_open_nar, vrach_ortoped, date_start_production, vrach_technic, date_close_nar, sum
    FROM j_nar
    WHERE id_patient = $1`, id)

    bks := make([]*SelectNar, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(SelectNar)
        rows.Scan(&bk.Id, &bk.NumberNar, &bk.DateOpenNar, &bk.VrachOrtoped, &bk.DateStartProduction, &bk.VrachTechnic, &bk.DateCloseNar, &bk.Sum)
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks
}
```

Как проверять на null значения при запросе insert в базу я разобрался, огромное спасибо: [chernomyrdin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176305/chernomyrdin)

Но не могу разобраться с проверкой на null в select. 
Если меняю тип в структуре на:

```
type SelectNar struct {

    Id          sql.NullString  `json:"id"`
    NumberNar       sql.NullString  `json:"number_nar"`
    DateOpenNar     sql.NullString  `json:"date_open_nar"`
    VrachOrtoped        sql.NullString  `json:"vrach_ortoped"`
    DateStartProduction sql.NullString  `json:"date_start_production"`
    VrachTechnic        sql.NullString  `json:"vrach_technic"`
    DateCloseNar        sql.NullString  `json:"date_close_nar"`
    Sum         sql.NullString  `json:"sum"`
}
```

То каждую запись получаю в таком формате.

{"String":"123","Valid":true},"date_open_nar"{"String":"","Valid":false},"vrach_ortoped":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
func EditModelListNarGet(id string) []*SelectNar {
    rows := db.Select(`
    SELECT
    id, number_nar, date_open_nar, vrach_ortoped, date_start_production, vrach_technic, date_close_nar, sum
    FROM j_nar
    WHERE id_patient = $1`, id)
    var NumberNarnullStr sql.NullString
    var DateOpenNarNullStr sql.NullString
    var VrachOrtopedNullStr sql.NullString
    var DateStartProductionNullStr sql.NullString
    var VrachTechnicNullstr sql.NullString
    var DateCloseNarNullStr sql.NullString
    var SummNulFloat64 sql.NullString
    bks := make([]*SelectNar, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(SelectNar)
        rows.Scan(&bk.Id, &NumberNarnullStr,  &DateOpenNarNullStr, &VrachOrtopedNullStr, &DateStartProductionNullStr, &VrachTechnicNullstr, &DateCloseNarNullStr, &SummNulFloat64)
        bk.NumberNar.String = NumberNarnullStr.String
        bk.DateOpenNar.String = DateOpenNarNullStr.String
        bk.VrachOrtoped.String = VrachOrtopedNullStr.String
        bk.DateStartProduction.String = DateStartProductionNullStr.String
        bk.VrachTechnic.String = VrachOrtopedNullStr.String
        bk.DateCloseNar.String = DateCloseNarNullStr.String
        bk.Sum.String = SummNulFloat64.String
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    return bks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так **Valid: false** и показывает, что значение в базе равно NULL. Соответственно при работе с **sql.nullString** для получения значения в виде строки надо обратиться к **String**, а для проверки на *null* - **Valid**.

Comment: я уже понял что для получения значения нужно к String обращаться, но не могу понять, как вывести пустые NULL значения... которые не NULL выводятся нормально.

Comment: Да, тренареика в golang жалко нету. А так отдельную функцию в которой проверяешь Valid и если не false, то возвращает строку, иначе - строка "[NULL]"

Comment: вот, не пойму как это сделать, уже всяко пытаюсь... в указателях и ссылках запутался...

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, что нужно сделать))) https://stackoverflow.com/a/33072822/3649235
Там описано как написать конвертер для JSON на примере **sql.NullInt64**.